# Using VBA in MS Word 2007 to define page elements?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-field

I'd like to be able to create a page element which I can feed text and it will form itself into the preferred layout. For instance:

```
{MACRO DocumentIntro("Introduction to Business Studies", "FP015", "Teachers' Guide")}
```

with that as a field, the output should be a line, the first two strings a certain size and font, centred, another line and then the third string fonted, sized and centred.

I know that's sort of TeX-like and perhaps beyond the scope of VBA, but if anyone's got any idea how it might be possible, please tell!

*EDIT*:

Ok, if I put the required information into Keyword, as part of the document properties, with some kind of unique separator, then that gets that info in, and the info will be unique to each document. Next one puts a bookmark where the stuff is going to be displayed. Then one creates an `AutoOpen` macro that goes to that bookmark, pulls the relevants out of the keywords, and forms the text appropriately into the bookmark's `.Selection`.

Is that feasible?

Comment: Interesting. Two quick questions: 1) Is this end-user feed, meaning they'll need a user-form of some sort? 2) Are you using Word 2007/Word 2010 or earlier versions?

Comment: 1) The only user is me. 2) Word 2007, though I've got the concept working 2003 (2007 at work, 2003 at home; what a pain ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're certainly on the right track here for a coding solution. However, there is a simpler way with no code - this is the type of scenario that Content Controls in Word 2007 were built for and with Fields/Properties, you can bind to content controls (CC). These CC can hold styles (like centered, bold, etc.). No VBA required.

The very easiest thing to do is to pick 3 built-in document properties that you will always want these to be. For example, "Title" could be your first string, "Subject" your second string and "Keywords" your third. Then, just go to the **Insert** ribbon, **Quick Parts**, **Document Properties** and insert, place and format those how you like. Then go to Word's start button (the orb thingy) and then under **Prepare** choose **Properties**. Here you can type, for example "*Introduction to Business Studies*", into the **Title** box and then just deselect it somehow (like click in another box). The Content Control for **Title** will be filled in automatically with your text.

If you want to use this for multiple files, just create this file as a .dotx (after CC insertion/placement/formatting and before updating the Document Properties' text). Then every time all you'll have to do is set these three properties with each new file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, it did turn out to be feasible.

```
Sub autoopen()
    Dim sKeywords As String
    sKeywords = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(4)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("foo").Select
    Selection.Text = sKeywords
End Sub
```

Okay, I have some filling out to do, but at least the guts of it are there.